# Fetch yesterday details using extract in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
consultation(patient_id, cdate, doctor_id)
```

I want the details of patients which was treated yesterday using extract 
But I am getting error

> ORA-00911: invalid character

My code:

```
select * 
from consultation 
where extract(day from cdate) = extract(day from sysdate) - '1';
```

Comment: use - extract(day from cdate) = extract(day from (sysdate-1)); And please keep in mind that only checking Day = Day will also return records from all other months as well. You should also consider Month and Year.

Comment: Why do you want to use extract? This way, if you run it now, you will even get April 7, March 7, and so on. Is this what you need?

Comment: That wouldn't give you results where cdate = yesterday, though. I think you're after `trunc(cdate) = trunc(sysdate -1)` or, if there's an index on cdate that you want to use, something like `cdate >= trunc(sysdate - 1) and cdate < trunc(sysdate)`

Answer (score 2):

You may avoid `extract` and simply use:

```
select *
from consultation 
where trunc(cdate) = trunc(sysdate-1)
```

Here I use `trunc` to remove the time part; also, notice that by using `extract` to compare the day, you will get not only records of yesterday, but even records from the past months.

If you need to get all the records where the day is 6 (assuming that sysdate is May, 7), no matter the month or year, you can use:

```
where extract(day from cDate) = extract(day from sysdate -1)
```

Comment: if i want from past months can i use trunc

Comment: `trunc(cdate) = trunc(extract(month from sysdate)-1)`
is it correct

Comment: I would use `add_months` rather than `extract` since extract wouldn't take account of the 31st; add_months would at least make 31st July match to 30th June.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer not to use `EXTRACT` on the date column, it is less efficient, especially if there's an index or partition on the date column. simply use `TRUNC` on `SYSDATE`

```
select * from consultation where 
     cdate  >= TRUNC(sysdate) - 1
 AND cdate  <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Comment: `trunc(cdate) = trunc(extract(month from sysdate)-1)`
is it correct for extracting data from previous month

Comment: @akacodes121 : This answers your original question.

Comment: I just want to ask can i use trunc for  previous month

Comment: @akacodes121 : As I said, you  first asked a question for yesterday and I've answered it. If you have a further question, You should ask a new one, that's the rule here in StackOverflow.

Comment: @KaushikNayak . . . This is the best solution because it allows the use of an index on the column.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put integer 1 not string '1'

```
select * from consultation where
extract(day from cdate) = extract(day from sysdate) - 1;
```

Comment: @akacodes121 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=32ee33e4e76aa37ebfa8a5f0fc868086 check this link it is working btw what is the data type of your cdate column

Comment: cdate data type is date